# open ajax modal after function is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open an ajax modal automatically after function is completed
It works everything but insted opening modal it goes to page i want to show by ajax .

I have these codes which i call ajax :

That is  how i call ajax HTML
    Ajax Content

that is jscode

```
Ajax
    */
    $('.simple-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax'
    });
```

Everything is okay here i can use ajax in this way perfectly but i want to call  that after a function is completed

i have that code i need to do:

```
this.finish = function(evt, opts)
  {
 $('.finish').show();
     $('#div').hide();

    $(".finish").on('click', function() {

    window.location = opts.return_url + redirect_params.toArray().join('&');
    });
  };
}
```

So after that function is finished i want or to open ajax automaticlly or by click this button .

```
<a  class="simple-ajax-popup btn btn-primary finish" style="display: none;" >ff</a>
```

Note: i need that document.location url in javascript ,, for that i cant use href directly at my button or whatever .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the href attribute of the a tag with

```
$(".finish").attr('href', utrl);
```

Then trigger the click event

```
 $(".finish").trigger('click');


this.finish = function(evt, opts){
     $('.finish').show();
     $('#div').hide();    
     $(".finish").attr('href',  opts.return_url + redirect_params.toArray().join('&'));

     $(".finish").trigger('click');
}
```